# Mnesia - aborted with bad_type when specifying storage strategy

Tags: erlang, mnesia

So I'm getting `{aborted,{bad_type,link,disc_copies, 'my_server@127.0.0.1'}}` (it is returned by my `init_db/0` function):

```
-record(link, {hash, original, timestamp}).
init_db() ->
    application:set_env(mnesia, dir, "/tmp/mnesia_db"),
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table( link,[
        {index,[timestamp]},
        {attributes, record_info(fields, link)},
        {disc_copies, [node()]}]).
```

Without `{disc_copies, [node()]}` table is properly created.

Answer (score 3):

Verify write permissions on the parent directory of the mnesia dir you're specifying via `application:set_env/3`. If the mnesia dir parent directory doesn't allow you to write, you'll get this error. (Another way to get this error is to forget to set mnesia dir entirely, but your `set_env` call is clearly doing that.)

**Update**: looking more carefully at your reported error, I see the node mentioned in the error is not in a list:

> {aborted,{bad_type,link,disc_copies, 'my_server@127.0.0.1'}}

This might mean that the code you show in your question doesn't match what's really running. Specifically, if you call `mnesia:create_table/2` passing a node instead of a list of nodes in the `disc_copies` tuple, as shown below, you'll get the same exact error:

```
mnesia:create_table(link,[{index,[timestamp]},
                          {attributes, record_info(fields, link)},
                          {disc_copies, node()}]). % note no list here, should be [node()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still get the error after making sure access privileges are fine.

Comment: @Update - you are not entirely right. The error indicating that there was not a list of nodes but a single node passed was produced but exactly the code pasted above. It looked suspicious for me, so I even tried to pass `{disc_copies, [[node()]]}` in my desperation, getting `{aborted,{bad_type,link,['my_server@127.0.0.1']}}`

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change the `schema` table to `disc_copies` which seems to affect the entire node.

```erlang
mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies)
```

From the mnesia docs:

> This function can also be used to change the storage type of the table named schema. The schema table can only have ram_copies or disc_copies as the storage type. If the storage type of the schema is ram_copies, no other table can be disc-resident on that node.

After this, you should be able to create `disc_copies` tables on the node.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
I received the `{aborted {bad_type,account,disc_copies,nonode@nohost}}` because I was calling the `mnesia:wait_for_tables` before the schema creation. Changing the order solved this for me.